# Will MATLAB 'move' or ''copy return value?

Tags: matlab

Given the following code

```
function [out] = doit() 
   out = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
end

tmp = doit();
```

Will MATLAB copy the memory of `out` to `tmp` or move it directly to `tmp`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is nothing like pointer in MATLAB, there are [local workspaces](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/base-and-function-workspaces.html).

It seems that MATLAB is smart and does a copy and return whenever needed and passes by "pointer" (without you knowing about it) if is not needed. As @Daniel and @zeeMonkeez pointed out, this is discussed in Loren's blog [here](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2006/05/10/memory-management-for-functions-and-variables), and she answers explicitly about function returns when memory has been created inside [here](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2006/05/10/memory-management-for-functions-and-variables/#comment-177). The general idea in those posts is "MATLAB will not copy unless its needed"

Basically MATLAB abstracts you from memory management.

---

*Sidenote*: There is something like pointers if you really need to exploit this. See @excaza's comment.

Comment: [You can have pointers (ish) in MATLAB](http://www.matlabtips.com/how-to-point-at-in-matlab/) :)

Comment: @excaza well, yeah technically true, you can do some weirdo things with it! But thats not the general case.

Comment: That is not true. Matlab uses copy-on-write which means `out` will never be duplicated.

Comment: Reference for copy on write: http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2006/05/10/memory-management-for-functions-and-variables/#comment-177

Comment: @excaza That article is dreadfully confused and misleading. A MATLAB handle variable is not a pointer, and MATLAB does not have pointers.

Comment: @AnderBiguri, Will copy-on-write work if we return a partial array, for example out(2:4)? I assume it would? although this may lead to some unused memory if its GC cannot free data partially.

Comment: @JoeC from Loren's comment (linked int he answer) it seems that in those cases, MATLAB will create a copy. If you are worried by memory, best catch everything and then slice it.

Comment: @AnderBiguri I see. What do you mean by catch and slice? Does it mean we first copy out(2:4) to a buffer and then return? That would lead to a copy anyway.

Comment: @JoeC I think (not sure) that returns a whole copy, and then it just takes the asked part.